Pine script v5 - Plot/Draw previous closing prices and extend to right
I want to plot/draw a horizontal line of the previous closing price and extend to right till it is crossed. I need to extend all the closing prices which are not crossed. Time frame is any timeframe.
I am new to pine script coding and getting error while trying different things.
Please help
I tried this
var float last_pdc = na
if na(last_pdc) or close > last_pdc or close < last_pdc
    last_pdc := pdc

d_pdc = plot(dpdc ? last_pdc : na, color=color.new(#c8055a, transp=40), title='PDC', linewidth=2, style=plot.style_cross, offset=offset)

but this is plotting only one and not multiple.

You need to decide what you want. 1. Have a visual guide that shows you where your previous close is crossed, or 2. have a condition that turns True when price crosses one of the previous closes. As you are new, these two presents two different problems for you, which you will need to learn.

close > last_pdc or close < last_pdc will be true for almost all candle as this condition is true when last_pdc is lower or higher than the close price which is what happens almost all the time.
